# Can Firestore support a single where query based on 5 between filters

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, indexing

I would like to know if a firestore collection of 10K records can support a query with 5 between filters. Eg.

```
Where (field_1 >= min_a and field_1 <= max_a) and
      (field_2 >= min_b and field_2 <= max_b) and
      (field_3 >= min_c and field_3 <= max_c) and
      (field_4 >= min_d and field_4 <= max_d) and
      (field_5 >= min_e and field_5 <= max_e)
```

Will I run into and index or query limitations?

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: I had missed that you're performing the range conditions on different fields. That is not supported, as shown in the documentation I linked.

---

Since you only have `AND` clauses you should not be hitting any limits. You *will* need to have an index that matches all the fields though, but the SDKs will raise an error if the necessary index is missing.

See the documentation for a list of the [limitations on Firestore's query capabilities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limits_on_or_queries)

Comment: Its not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this isn't possible. The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) states

*In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.*